# Azure API Management Usage Pattern for Enterprise

Tags: api, azure, azure-api-management

Consider the following scenario:

- I have a 100 people in one org with 4 divisions
- I create on Azure API Management instance
- All 100 people are developing APIs and adding them to this single API management instance

Can I achieve following? If yes, how?

I want to group the APIs by those 4 division. Allow access of APIs only if it is added by people in their division. When I say allow access, basically I mean search the APIs and call the APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using "Groups". First, you need to have a group per division. You can either manually create the groups and add users to them or if you use Azure Active Directory and enable developers to login with AAD to the portal, then their existing group membership will also be available to use.

Once you have the group set up you need to have a product for each group. You can set the visibility settings of the product so that only members of a given group can see it. Then you can set which APIs the product contains and thus complete the mapping of groups to APIs.